# How to handle pop up/alert in selenium RC

Tags: popup, selenium-rc, alert, selenium-ide

I faced a problem while trying to automate a web-application using Selenim RC.

On clicking a button I got a pop-up which has a button to be clicked to proceed. Further, on recording thru IDE found that Pop-up button property as Xpath, also tried to find the window id or window name, alert but all are returning as false,so couldn't get the properties of the Pop-up and able to proceed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the window doesn't have id or name. try to capture the xpath of the window which is embedded inside the main window(as seen from the screenshot) using Firebug and use

```
  selenium.focus(embedded window xpath)
```

after that perform the remaining operations on the selected window. Once finished, get back to the main window using

```
 selenium.selectWindow(main window name/id)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it looks like this is not a popup window. This is just another element, except the background is modal. These are modal popups.

Just like a normal button in the screen, you can wait for the button to be present and then click on the button. You can use id,name, xpath or css to locate the button.